# Docker: pip install -e . works but pip install -r requirements.txt does not work

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have a flask python 3.7 app that I want to run on docker and Kubernetes.

I have following Docker files

**This one works (using python eggs)**

```
FROM python:3-stretch
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -e . 
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "myapp/application.py"]
```

**But this does not (but I want to stick to this)**

```
FROM python:3-stretch
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "myapp/application.py"]
```

Running this command (after building the container)
`docker run -it -p 5000:5000 myapp-python:latest`
gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp/application.py", line 3, in <module>
    import myapp.config as config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'
```

But as mentioned above this works perfectly fine with the previous Docker file. Any help is much appreciated.

Additional notes:

- No errors while building the Docker container

Here is my requirements.txt

```
flask
requests
flask-restful
flask-migrate
flask-sqlalchemy
flask-marshmallow
flask-jwt-extended
marshmallow-sqlalchemy
python-dotenv
passlib
tox
neomodel==3.2.9
marshmallow>=3.0.0b11
apispec
phonenumbers
pillow
emailage>=1.1.2
emailage-official==1.0.2
boto3
geopy
fuzzywuzzy
py2neo>=4.1.0
python-dotenv
eth_utils
neo4j>=1.7.0
neotime>=1.7.1
python-jose
eth-utils
eth-hash[pycryptodome]
python-Levenshtein
jsonpatch
google-cloud-vision
google-cloud-translate
pycountry
sspyjose>=0.2.5
pysinglesource>=0.1.0
flask-cors
pynamodb
```

Comment: The second one only installs the requirements, not the application itself.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Can you please elaborate a bit more? how can I fix it. I'm not very familiar with python eggs.

Comment: I'm thinking that the second one can't find your project in `PYTHONPATH`, since it seems to be running the `application.py` file as specified in `CMD`, but can't import the `config.py` file.

Comment: if it's python3, shouldn't it be `pip3 install`?

Comment: @suren. Nope. I just ran that docker image for python:3-stretch to check, and pip works just fine - it defaults to `pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. I built the two containers separately
2. Then inside each container ran the following command.

```
root@64118c352a3e:/app# python
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/app', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Then found out in my second config I was missing the `'/app'` path in the second container.

Then I added the path using

`ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/app"`

Full Dockerfile looks like following.

```
FROM python:3-stretch
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTONPATH}:/app"
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "myapp/application.py"]
```

Now it works.

Hope this will help someone

Comment: What is the content of the `requirements.txt`? It looks like you are not actually installing your application but only its requirements. Changing the `PYTHONPATH` should not be necessary. Proof of this is that it works with `pip install -e .`. Looks like you need a `pip install .` in there somewhere.

Comment: @sinoroc not sure if I understand this "It looks like you are not actually installing your application but only its requirements". Someone else also mentioned this but I don't know how to address this. I tried adding this but it doesn't work `pip install .`. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: It is a bit difficult to pinpoint without knowing more about your exact setup, but something doesn't seem right. First there's rarely a good reason to modify `PYTHONPATH`. Does your project have a correctly functioning `setup.py`? Can you update the question with the content of your `requirements.txt`?